# How do i return a string without a specified length in c?

Tags: c, function, c-strings

i am trying to reverse a string in c. But i cant figure out how to return the string from my function.Heres my code

```
int len(char string[]) {
    int i = 0;
    while (string[i] != 0) {
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}
char* reverse(char string[])
{
    static char reversedString[len(string)];
    for (int i = 0;string[i] != 0;i++) {
        reversedString[i] = string[len(string)-i];
    }
    return reversedString;
}
int main(void) {
    char a[5] = "abcde";

    printf("%s",reverse(a));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If that still doesn't help then suggest you fire up your favourite search engine and type in "return a string from a function in C".

Comment: char a[5] = "abcde";   there is NO space for the null terminator.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning a static char array, just reverse the string in
place.

```
char* reverse(char* string)
{
  const int n = len(string);
  for (int i = 0; i < n / 2; ++i)
  {
    char tmp = string[i];
    string[i] = string[n - 1 - i];
    string[n - 1 - i] = tmp;
  }
  return string;
}
```

Of course you only do half the string (i < n/2), since otherwise it will return the string in original order.